# MongoDB search query with specific id

Tags: database, mongodb, api

```
{ _id: ObjectId("62541083e601e0bddf0e1681"),
  name: 'Monitioir',
  brand: 'sonic',
  price: 70000,
  category: 'monitor',
  user_id: '62541073e601e0bddf0e167d',
  __v: 0 }


{ _id: ObjectId("62540d527fe95cb11db5ad86"),
  name: 'Laptop 8 GB Ram',
  brand: 'DEL',
  price: 60000,
  category: 'laptop',
  user_id: '62517edb7fc85c423a5b12c3',
  __v: 0 }
```

I have a 2 products in my collection inserted by 2 different users in front-end I am creating a search bar where user can search only the products added by him only the search api that I have created is also returning the products added by the other users also my query is

```
db.products.find({$or:[{name:{$regex:"o"}}]})
```

after executing this query both users products are coming i want only of specific user.

Comment: you are querying by name and regex with o, both contain this? Are you trying to query by user_id?

Comment: For example, if the user whose user_id is  "62517edb7fc85c423a5b12c3" is searching 'o' in the front-end I want to show only the products added by him only not all.

Comment: can you include more code like front end what you send, backend api controller?

Comment: You should include the `user_id` also, if you are searching by name and user_id. To search by two fields, you can use the `$and` operator.